# How to use a class method as a parameter (variable)?

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, call

I am creating software with multilingual functionality. I am thinking about how to separate and easily call texts in different languages. Here is what I got:

```
import tkinter as tk  # GUI

class Texts():

    def __init__(self, txtENG, txtRU):
        self.txtENG = txtENG
        self.txtRU = txtRU

    def txt_ENG(self):
        return self.txtENG  # should return English text

    def txt_RU(self):
        return self.txtRU  # should return Russian text


language_Q = 'Choose the language:' 
language_A = ['English','русский']  # two options for OptionMenu

txt_ENG_greetings = 'Hello!'  # English text
txt_RU_greetings = 'Привет!'  # Russian text

  # initializing English and Russian texts to Texts class as greetings attribute
greetings = Texts(txt_ENG_greetings, txt_RU_greetings)


def secondstep():

      # assigning methode as a variable according to chosen option
    if q1.get() == 'English': language = Texts.txt_ENG
    if q1.get() == 'русский': language = Texts.txt_RU

      # label that should display greetings called by the right methode 
    greetings_label = tk.Label(window, text = greetings.language()).grid(row=3)

    window.mainloop()


window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Hello StackerOverflow')

  # option menu to choose the language
q1 = tk.StringVar(window); q1.set(language_Q)
w = tk.OptionMenu(window, q1, *language_A).grid(row=0);

  # button to call secondstep function
button = tk.Button(window, text='Continue', command=secondstep).grid(row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Code does not work. I have a problem using a methode as a parameter. Error:

```
   greetings_label = tk.Label(window, text = greetings.language()).grid(row=3)
AttributeError: 'Texts' object has no attribute 'language'
```

I have spent a lot of time trying fixing this but got nothing, so if it is impossible, what would be the best alternative? Thank you!

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel..? Use `gettext` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your second step to call the language variable. Because the Object Texts has no method `language()`. Furthermore, you need to store the method of the object not of the class to actually run it.

```py
def secondstep():
    # assigning methode as a variable according to chosen option
    if q1.get() == 'русский':
        language = greetings.txt_RU
    else:  # have a default selection.
        language = greetings.txt_ENG

    # label that should display greetings called by the right method
    greetings_label = tk.Label(window, text=language()).grid(row=3)

    window.mainloop()
```